# Slow hotspot on MacBook Pro using new iPhone 14 pro

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi, tethering

MacBook is slow on my Hotspot with my iPhone 14.

On my phone, I get 300Mbs+ downloads. Using my Hotspot, my computer is rated at .19Mbps

I have a brand new iPhone 14 and a MacBook Pro 16 [2021]

[image: Speed Test Image 1]

[image: Speed Test Image 2]

Comment: Is the hotspot using Bluetooth or WiFi?

Answer (score 2):

What IP address is assigned to your Macbook Pro when connected to the hotspot? The following command should provide the info (run from Terminal or iTerm)

```
networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi
```

I'm curious because I've recently started experiencing poor hotspot performance with my Macbook Pro M1 using an iPhone 15. In my case, when things were working great my Macbook was issued a 172.20.10.2 / 255.255.255.240 address with gateway 172.20.10.1

Now it's assigned a weird address: 192.0.0.2 with gateway 192.0.0.1 (subnet mask is empty).

Manually setting the IP the 172.... address above fixes things.

```
#!/bin/bash

ip_manual="172.20.10.2"
ip_dhcp="192.0.0.2"

cleanup() {
  IP=$(networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep '^IP address:' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')
  if [[ "$IP" == "$ip_manual" ]]; then
    echo "Setting Wi-Fi interface to DHCP"
    networksetup -setdhcp Wi-Fi
    sleep 2
    networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -v IPv6
  fi
  on_campus_hosts
}

# Trap shutdown to reset Wi-Fi IP back to DCHP
# networksetup -setdhcp Wi-Fi
trap cleanup SIGINT

# Check to see if we have a 192.0.0.2 IP address. This comes from my iPhone
#   hotspot and SSH via SShuttle doesn't work. Change it to the old hotspot IP
#   172.20.10.2 / 255.255.255.240
IP=$(networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep '^IP address:' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')
if [[ "$IP" == "$ip_dhcp" ]]; then
  echo "Setting IP manually to $ip_manual for interface Wi-Fi"
  networksetup -setmanual Wi-Fi $ip_manual 255.255.240.0 172.20.10.1
  networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -v IPv6
fi
```